# How to install upgrade to new version of awstats Linux / UNIX *.tar.gz tarball files

Tags: linux, installation, makefile, awstats, make-install

I currently have awstats 7.0 which is from 2010.  I would like to update to current stable relase, which is awstats 7.3

I tried

tar zxf awstats-7.3.tar.gz
cd awstats-7.3
ls  -al

drwxr-xr-x 5 puter puter 4096 Jan 29  2014 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 puter puter 4096 Jan 24 23:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 puter puter 4096 Jan 29  2014 docs
-rw-r--r-- 1 puter puter 7020 Jan 29  2014 README.TXT
drwxr-xr-x 5 puter puter 4096 Nov  4  2013 tools
drwxr-xr-x 7 puter puter 4096 Nov  4  2013 wwwroot

./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

make
make:  No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

make install
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.

???

please, advise.  Thank you.

I also followed this link
http://www.awstats.org/docs/awstats_upgrade.html

however, I dont really know where to distribute the files on the system.

lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 (wheezy)
Release:    7.5
Codename:   wheezy

Comment: why did this post get -1? I tried several ways of updating the awstats without success. Debian Wheezy doesnt have the latest version, and there isnt a .deb file from awstats. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first command you try to run (`./configure`) fails (*No such file or directory*), then probably you should stop right there.  The rest of the commands won't work any better.

Did you read the `README.TXT` file?

Awstats doesn't seem to be a program that needs to be compiled, and it doesn't have a `configure` script (obviously since you showed the list of files and there isn't one there).  I googled for "awstats install" and found [this page](http://www.awstats.org/docs/awstats_setup.html) where it says:

> After downloading and extracting the AWStats package, you should run the awstats_configure.pl script to do several setup actions. You will find it in the AWStats tools directory

and you clearly have a `tools` directory, so I would start with that.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I did read the readme.txt.  I just wanted to update the script.  And I couldnt find the old installation directory, and how it was distributed in the system. Awstats prefers to place it at /usr/local/awstats.  However, when you use 'apt-get install awstats', Debian Wheezy doesnt place it there.  So, I figured the best method was to create a deb. I did find deb files online, but didnt trust the source since it wasnt from awstats.  I just removed the old version, and I installed the new version manually to /usr/local/awstats.  Thank you once again.